# Cant use more then 2 layouts

Tags: android, class, layout, button, crash

I am trying to make a android application with many xml layouts, but i get a problem here. 
the problem starts at the second button then the application crashes.

```
public class MonkeyQuest_androidActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button newGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
    newGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.name);
            final Button setName= (Button) findViewById(R.id.setName);
            setName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.Menu);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean, "many XML layouts"?  Do you mean that you need many activities?  It looks like you are trying to change the layout multiple times for one activity?  What do you mean "the problem starts at the second button"?  What second button?  Are you getting an exception? What is the exception?  Please post the logcat (only the relevant bit) and more information on what you are trying to achieve and why.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the Content View to a new layout, launch a new activity and set the Content View in that Activity's `onCreate()`, same way you do in this activity.

Launch the new activity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Read more: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/android-full-app-part-5-launch-activity.html#ixzz1ljJohpib

Otherwise, any Views you've declared in the activity will be behind the new inflated View (unless reinstantiated), and that could cause a lot of other problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to call `setContentView()` more than once per activity.

If you want to switch layouts you either need to create a new activity to go in to, or put all of the Views you want into your one layout and hide/show only the relevant ones with setVisibility(), or with something like a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)